# vscode: how to avoid "quick open"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm new to vscode. In other IDEs, when I hold CTRL button, put my cursor of method name and make a left mouse click, I'm navigated to a new tab in the IDE that includes the method definition.

However, in vscode, when I do it, I see this appearance:

[image]

A new windows is opened inside the current tab. I just want the "regular" behavior.

I edited settings.json file and added:

```
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
"workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen": false
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work out.

Do you know what can help in this case?

Comment: FWIW: this widget is called `Peek` and those settings `workbench.editor.enablePreview` are not in any way related to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"editor.gotoLocation.multiple": "goto",
```

Controls the behavior of 'Go To' commands, like Go To Definition, when multiple target locations exist.

---

Alternatively/additionally show references in the SideBar:

```
"references.preferredLocation": "view",
```